# Help with model answer for time complexity

Tags: time-complexity, big-o-notation

Hi I cannot understand why the best case for line 3 is `n-1` and why it isnt just always `n`?

I tried to write this in python to understand when it would be `n-1` and the answer is always `n`. I am assuming that the loop counter in pseudo-code is evaluated one more time than the body is executed as is said in the Cormen book.

My thinking is that if the length of `n` is 1, the loop evaluation is still tested so regardless the answer would still be `n`, even if the loop body itself did not run.

```
Max(A)

1 MaxInt = A[1]
2 index = 2
3 while index ≤ n // Why is the best n-1 here?
4   if MaxInt < A[index]
5     MaxInt = A[index]
6   index = index+1
7 return MaxInt
```

I know it has to be something very simple but I cant seem to work it out as testing with 1 or 1000 the answer I get back for a count is always `n-1` (0, 999) and if I assume that the loops asserts a final time that is + 1, so `0 + 1 = 1`, which is `n` and `999 + 1 = 1000` which is `n`.

Comment: The best case is for the smallest number of iterations !

Answer (score 0):

The loop body will be executed $n - 1$ times because your `index` variable is initially set to $2$ rather than $1$.
Hence, at the start of the loop body, the values for `index` are from the range $\{2, 3, ..., n\}$, which has $n - 1$ elements.

Comment: Yes and that makes sense but line 3 is the loop evaluation?

Comment: If the worst for line 3 is`n`, and the best for line 3 is `n - 1` (according to the answer sheet), when will it actually be `n` then, using your example? I thought from reading the book the loop evaluation would happen one last time even when the loop body doesnt execute, so if it is n -1 (as you suggest), when is it n?

Answer (score 0):

The number of iterations of the body of the loop is $\max(0,n-1)$.

The number of comparisons performed at line $3$ is $\max(1,n)$.

For both, best case and worst case are identical. If the answer sheet says otherwise, it is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that after index is incremented from n to n+1 by line 6, the condition in line 3 is tested one last time (this condition evaluates to False because index=n+1, which is not <=n) before the while loop exists.

Line 3 is executed for the first time when index = 2, and executed for the last time when index = n + 1.  Hence, the total number of times line 3 is executed is n.  Lines 4-6 are executed when index takes values 2 to n, and hence are executed n-1 times.